# Simulation of multiple binomial random numbers in R

Tags: r, algorithm, random, statistics, simulation

I have the following algorithm

Step 1. Generate X1=x1~Bin(6,1/3)

Step 2. Generate X2|X1=x1~Bin(6-x1,(1/3)/(1-1/3))

Step 3. Generate X3|X1=x1,X2=x2~Bin(6-x1-x2,(1/3)/(1-1/3-1/3))

Step 4. Repeat step 1-3 N times.

Here is my approach to implement this algorithm in R:

```
mult_binom<-function(n) #n=6
{
  n=1000
  random_vectors<-Matrix(0,n,3)

  for(i in 1:n){

    X1<-rbinom(n,3,1/3) 

    X2<-rbinom(n-X1,3,(1/3)/(1-(1/3)))

    X3<-rbinom(n-X1-X2,3,(1/3)/(1-(1/3)-(1-3)))


    arr<-c(X1,X2,X3)


  }
  for(j in 1:n){

    random_vectors[j]<-arr[j]
  }
  return(random_vectors)
}
```

Calling the function as `mult_bin(6)` yields a *similar* matrix as the below one

```
1000 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

  [1,] 1 . .
  [2,] 1 . .
  [3,] 1 . .
  [4,] 2 . .
  [5,] 1 . .
  [6,] 1 . .
  [7,] 1 . .
  [8,] . 3 .
```

and continues up to [1000,]

I was not expecting this result.

Why are dots there?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: @Cettt why did you remove my questions about the dots and the unique numbers 1 2 and 3?

Comment: I think the key message was that you did not understood the output as a whole and that the dots were only a little part of the overall problem. I am sorry if I was wrong about that. But keeping the question short and compact usually results in more people reading them and hence yields better answers.

Comment: @Cettt I did understand the output as a whole (I was expecting an `nx3` matrix) and yes the dots were only a little part of the overall problem. The numbers 1 2 and 3 too. I know now why there were only 1, 2,3.

Comment: @Cettt :) Actually only the dots part is necessary now. So would be more short and compact. You're right indeed that _short and compact usually results in more people reading them and hence yields better answers._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several errors in your implementation. The most important one is that the first argument of `rbinom` is not the parameter `n` from the binomial distribution but the number of random numbers you want to generate.

Here is my solution. My function only returns on experiment. I then use replicate to return the result of multiple (in my case 5) experiments:

```
myfun <- function(){

  x1 <- rbinom(1, 6, 1/3) 
  x2 <- rbinom(1, 6 - x1, (1/3)/(1-(1/3)))
  x3 <- rbinom(1, 6 - x1 - x2, (1/3)/(1-(1/3)-(1/3)))

  return(c(X1 = x1, X2 = x2, X3 = x3))  
}

    set.seed(1)
    replicate(5, myfun())
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
X1    1    4    4    0    3
X2    2    0    1    2    1
X3    3    2    1    4    2
```

In this output every column is the result of one experiment. You can see that the numbers always add up to 6.
Note also, that I set a random seed with `set.seed`. This ensures that your results are reproducible.

In your output the dots appear because you use the `Matrix` package to create a `Matrix` object instead of working with "normal" matrices. Usually you create a matrix with `matrix`  not  `Matrix`.

Comment: Why do you use `replicate(5, myfun())` instead of a `loop` ?

Comment: there are two reasons to prefer replicate instead of loops:
First: replicate is faster than a for loop. Second: it is easier to read and write replicate instead of a loop.
Concerning the dots I recommend reading the manual of the `Matrix` package:   basically a dot represents a zero.